# Thread not running, and why is jframe setresizeable not working

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, jframe

Why is this program not working? (It doesn't print "Running...")

```
package eu.inmensia.learn;

import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Dimension;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Client extends Canvas implements Runnable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public static final int WIDTH = 300;
    public static final int HEIGHT = WIDTH / 16 * 9;
    public static final short SCALE = 3;

    private Thread thread;
    private JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    private boolean running = false;

    public Client() {
        Dimension size = new Dimension(WIDTH * SCALE, HEIGHT * SCALE);
        setPreferredSize(size);
    }

    public synchronized void start() {
        running = true;
        thread = new Thread("display");
        thread.start(); // start the thread
    }

    public synchronized void stop() {
        running = false;
        try{
            thread.join(); // end the thread
        }catch(InterruptedException e){ e.printStackTrace(); }
    }

    public void run() {
        while(running){
            System.out.println("Running...");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Client client = new Client();
        client.frame.setResizeable(false);
        client.frame.setTitle("Program test");
        client.frame.add(client);
        client.frame.pack();
        client.frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        client.frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        client.frame.setVisible(true);

        client.start();
    }
}
```

I'm trying to learn threads, and it's one, if not the most hard, thing I ever have learned. OOP is nothing to this xD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of this

```
new Thread("display");
```

Change it to

```
new Thread(this)
```

I just hope you know what you're doing.

Comment: Thanks, now I see it! Just forgotten to add it. (PS. I changed it to new Thread(this, "display), it also works.

Answer (score 2):

you do this in wrong way,
when you call `client.start();` it will call start function in the `Client` class and in that function you make a new instance of thread class that has the default `run` method that is empty

you may mean this code:

```
public synchronized void start() {
    running = true;
    thread = new Thread(this);
    thread.start(); // start the thread
}
```

I hope this help you

Answer (score 0):

You have created a generic (read BLANK) thread object. You need to pass in your class as a parameter.

```
thread = new Thread(this);
```

This will bind your run method to the Thread object. The name of the thread is usually not so important. Refer to [this example](http://www.go4expert.com/forums/showthread.php?t=4202)